# Plugin with MAF AddInProcess and Telerik RadRibbonView causes exception

Tags: c#, telerik, maf, system.addin

I have designed an API using System.AddIn (MAF) in order to allow the loading of WPF Plugins in isolation from the Host.

Currently the API uses AppDomains to provide the separation, however due to the limitations associated with AppDomains I am trying to switch the implementation over to using AddInProcesses instead.  I've been using the following project as a template: http://www.cnblogs.com/Files/sheva/Process.zip

My initial implementation seems to work ok and I am able to load WPF elements across the isolation boundary, but I have found issues when attempting to load complex Telerik controls eg. RadRibbonView, resulting in the following exception:

`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Failed to read from an IPC Port: The pipe has been ended.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by an exception occuring on the plugin side while trying to load the UI elements.  I managed to resolve it by attaching to the plugin's process and stepping through the code that serves up the UI to the host.